# MySQL and Bit Bashing

Tags: mysql

I'm using [Bit bashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) on SQL for user rights, like UNIX rights :

> 1 - 001 - Execute
>
> 2 - 010 - Write
>
> 4 - 100 - Read

So if I have right 6 ( 2+4 or 110) I can write AND read but I can't execute. On my case i have many more rights, so my users can have the value "128" for rights.

How can I do a query and ask all used with a right (like 2 for UNIX example)

```
SELECT * from user WHERE user_right ?? '2'
```

The users rights must be 2 (010), 3 (011), 6 (110) or 7 (111) ?!

Thank you all and sorry for my English :/

Comment: You are aware of [the bitwise operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html)? There is a good set of examples at the bottom of the docs (user-contrib)

Comment: Thank you for this documentation ! I had never seen bit operator on MYSQL :)

Good query : SELECT * from user WHERE user_right & 2

Comment: you might not want to throw around hip terms like bit bashing if you don't know how to actually leverage bit manipulation.

Comment: I use often on PHP for users right, but never on SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

128 would mean there were 7 total user rights:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 0177 = 0x7F = 127
```

MySQL already has an abstraction for this, known as the [`SET` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html), which essentially maps your named/visible value for the right to a binary value. So if you had a set column user_right:

```
('Execute', 'Write', 'Read')
```

They would actually be stored on the server backend as:

```
(1, 2, 4)
```

This allows for normal queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_right LIKE '%Write%';
```

or using `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Write',user_right) > 0;
```

or direct bitset operations:

```
SELECT * from user WHERE user_right & 2;
```

to name a few. If you add an `ORDER BY user_right` to your select queries, it returns them in their numerical (not alphabetical) order, but otherwise you can quickly determine the values of a user with:

```
SELECT user_name, user_right FROM user;
```

and seeing that the returned value is:

```
'some user' | Read,Write
```

while still having the benefits of bitwise operations for very fast filtering, such as:

```
SELECT user_name, user_right FROM user WHERE user_right & ~1;
```

to return all users with read and write permissions that do not have execute rights.

Comment: Storing more than one value in a single column is against 1NF.

Comment: SET stores the bitset of the defined options, which is what the OP is doing as well. So either the question violates normalization and the answer shows a predefined way to do so, or you don't see how they are the same, which means you're spouting off normalization rules out you don't actually understand.  Either way, this solution is built into mysql and performs better than the OPs homemade approach.

Comment: Be sure to tell children not to split their infinitives later, after ensuring everyone knows that an XML id can contain a dot but shouldn't.

Comment: Just because it's built in doesn't mean it's designed to be sargable (`LIKE '%...%'` and `FIND_IN_SET`), so why would you recommend this?

Comment: First, I reccomended it to save the user the trouble of a similar approach that is not as well integrated.  Second, I have no idea what sargable means, and thus didn't suggest it was such. Finally, the argument regarding enums and sets in rdbms is old and won't get settled here, so if you would like to offer the OP an alternative, I think you should. I choose to improve on their chosen approach. Sorry if that's not gargle enough for you.